# Python-Microsoft SQL Insert Variables into Table

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

There is a working request:

```
MSQSLQuferty1="""INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES('namedd188','logindd188','passworddd',0)"""
cursor.execute(MSQSLQuferty1)
```

But if you pass parameters through variables, an error occurs.

```
name1="ur2241"
login1="login2241"
password1="password2241"
voises1="0"

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.Users(name,login,password,Voited) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s);"%(name1,login1,password1,voises1))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "E:/Dropbox/Pyton/Network/Client-Server/Server/SQLConnect.py",
>   line 33, in 
>       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.Users(name,login,password,Voited) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s);"%(name1,login1,password1,voises1))   File
>   "E:\Pyton\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py",
>   line 1626, in execute   File
>   "E:\Pyton\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py",
>   line 1652, in execdirect   File
>   "E:\Pyton\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py",
>   line 1007, in check_success   File
>   "E:\Pyton\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py",
>   line 975, in ctrl_err pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', '[42S22]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Недопустимое имя
>   столбца "ur2241".')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)
```

with

```
VALUES ('%s','%s','%s',%s)
```